# I don't see Bartik as theme to enable

Tags: 10

I have reached a "screeching halt" trying to upgrade D9.5 to D10. So, I thought it might be better to "simply" start afresh with "vanilla" D10 and migrate stuff manually. Now I have a problem:
Under D8/9 I have been using a subtheme of Bartik with an involved coloring scheme. I see that Bartik is still availabe as a contributed project. But - can it be used by simply installing it under a "vanilla" D10, without first installing it under D9 and then upgrading to D10. I downloaded Bartik in D10 using composer require drupal/bartik:^1.0. But, going to "Design" under D10, I don't now see Bartik as a choice to activate. Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the deprecation documentation from August 2022 answer your question? https://www.drupal.org/node/3304352. Does the deprecated and obsolete extensions page answer your question? https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/deprecated-and-obsolete#s-recommendations-for-deprecated-themes It reads "the contributed project works with Drupal 9 and Drupal 10". The contributed theme is not marked as hidden or experimental so it is possible there was an issue installing it on your end.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install both Bartik **and** Classy using composer and to add `dependency: classy` in my composer.json.

Answer (score -1):

The Bartik theme is available here : https://www.drupal.org/project/bartik

Comment: The OP is aware of that, according to the Question.